# dynamic drop down menus

Tags: javascript, php

I have set of drop down menus that i use across my web site that are dynamically generated by PHP, i use these drop down menus slightly different on each page, one page 1 I only want to display drop down menu 1 with options and based on the selection display another drop down menu. To achieve this I am using JS but at the beginning all three possible drop down menus are displayed but only one sopose to be visible.

JS code:

```
function test(){

    //if getElementById('workshop'). exists display none to getElementById('Binary') document.getElementById('Forex').
    if(document.getElementById('workshop')){
        document.getElementById('Forex').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('Binary').style.display = 'none';
    }


    //diSPLAY LOGICS BY document.getElementById('workshop')

    if(document.getElementById('workshop').value == 'Forex'){
        document.getElementById('Forex').style.display = 'inline-block';
        document.getElementById('Forex').name = 'workshop';
    }else{
        document.getElementById('Forex').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('Forex').name = '';
    }

    if(document.getElementById('workshop').value == 'BinaryOptions'){
        document.getElementById('Binary').style.display = 'inline-block';
        document.getElementById('Binary').name = 'workshop';
    }else{
        document.getElementById('Binary').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('Binary').name = '';
    }



}
```

PHP code (part of it to give an idea):

```
function getForex($link){
```

$timestamp = date("Y-m-d");

```
$sql = "SELECT id, course, status, endingDate FROM courses WHERE course LIKE '%Forex%' OR  course LIKE '%forex%' AND status=5";
$query = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    $option='<select id="Forex" name="workshop">';
    $option.='<option value="">Select Forex Workshop</option>';
    $option.='';
        while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
        {
            if($timestamp < $result['endingDate'])
            {
                $option.='<option id="'.$result['id'].'" value='.$result['endingDate'].'>'.$result['course'].$result['endingDate'].'</option>'; 
            }
        }
        $option.='</select>';
        return $option;             
}
```

Comment: So you only want one drop down to show, correct? What is the criteria for each drop down?

Comment: yes on one of the pages I want one to appear with options and based on these options to show another drop down menu, but all three possible menue shop up at start